# How do I turn off touch bar's auto brightness adjustment? I want it to be at the same brightness level in all lighting conditions.

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, high-sierra

I have checked all the options provided in the display, keyboard, and power save settings. Is there any way I could set the touch-bar brightness to a constant level. My laptop specs are as follows:

Macbook Pro 15 inch 2018, Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: I'm looking for the same option as well on my **MacBook Pro 13" (2019), macOS Catalina 10.15.4**.